# Starting Celery on openshift

Tags: python, flask, celery, openshift

I'm currently writing a flask application and going to use openshift. I start my worker in my dev environment using

```
celery worker -A wsgi.app
```

My question is how do I start my celery worker in openshift? Because if I started in the openshift shell when I exit the shell the process is killed and my background workers never run so the flask application never runs correctly.
I really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't try like this

```
celery multi start worker1 \
    --pidfile="$HOME/run/celery/%n.pid" \
    --logfile="$HOME/log/celery/%n.log"
```

where mentioned [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html?highlight=daemon)

Comment: Does it last? Or is it killed when the gear goes down?

Comment: @Radek is asking the real question here :)

Comment: It doesn't last.  I was running a very intensive image manipulation and the system kept restarting and I would lose it. Managing it with cron worked as far as restarting but results were lost. I need sudo somewhere else.